# flask request data empty

Tags: python, flask, axios

Request header (via `print request.headers`):

```
Origin: null
Content-Length: 15
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Mobile Safari/537.36
Connection: keep-alive
Host: <host>
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[1B blob data]
```

`print request.from` gives `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

`print request.args` gives `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

`print request.data` gives `[object Object]`

`print request.is_json` gives `True` ....

after calling `request.get_json()` it immediately responses with 404

How can I get my post data?

flask function calls with `cross_origin` decorator

update:

function code:

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def register():
    print request.headers
    print '~~~~~~~~'
    print request.form 
    print request.args
    #print request.data
    print request.is_json
    print request.accept_mimetypes
    print request.get_json()
    return '', 200
```

update2:

when I send post via http in terminal it works correctly and gives Content-Length: 16, but when I send post via axios in react it gives 400 and Content-Length: 15. Other headers the same.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it's problem with axios, it can't get dict as post data, so I pass arguments with `JSON.stringify(data_dict)` in react and `json.loads(request.data)` in flask